# How does gravitational time dilation apply to observers in free-fall?

Tags: general-relativity, time-dilation

My question is whether an observer in free-fall about a massive object experiences the gravitational time dilation associated with that object.

Apparently the answer is "yes it does".

What I still can't understand is why the free-fall observer experiences no other effects of the gravitational field, except the gravitational time dilation.

I guess I'm asking do ISS astronauts suffer the same gravitational time dilation as people standing on the Earth (ignoring the height difference and velocity time dilation).

But, of course, the free fall observer would not know that their time was dilated - maybe that is the answer.

Comment: Voting to reopen. A perfectly clear question although based on some misunderstandings about time dilation - but we don't close questions just because the questioner has misunderstandings.

Answer (score 8):

Time dilation is a comparison between the time coordinate of some coordinate system and the proper time along some worldline. The time dilation factor $\gamma$ is given by $$\frac{1}{\gamma}=\frac{d\tau}{dt}$$ where $t$ is the time coordinate and $\tau$ is the proper time.

All coordinate systems agree on $\tau$ (it is invariant) but different coordinate systems disagree on $t$ and therefore they disagree on $\gamma$. This means that the time dilation can change by changing the coordinate system, without changing anything physical. In your case, in the earth’s frame (Schwarzschild coordinates) the astronauts are time dilated, but in the ISS frame they are not.

> My question is whether an observer in free-fall about a massive object experiences the gravitational time dilation associated with that object

I don’t think the word “experiences” is appropriate. However, it is correct that in the earth’s coordinate system the astronaut is time dilated.

> What I still can't understand is why the free-fall observer experiences no other effects of the gravitational field, except the gravitational time dilation

Here it seems you are using the word “experiences” inconsistently. In the earth’s coordinates the astronaut is gravitationally time dilated and gravitationally accelerated. In the ISS coordinates the astronaut is neither gravitationally time dilated nor gravitationally accelerated. However, be aware that gravitational time dilation is related to the gravitational potential, not the gravitational acceleration.

> I guess I'm asking do ISS astronauts suffer the same gravitational time dilation as people standing on the Earth (ignoring the height difference and velocity time dilation)

The time dilation in the Earth’s coordinate system is related to the height and the velocity. So if you ignore those things then there is no time dilation.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the question is about the equivalence principle, and where to use it.

Suppose that instead of falling into a massive body, the observer was being approached by an accelerated frame moving to him. In this case, he would be in an inertial frame in a Minkowski space-time.

From the point of view of the observer, applying the equivalence principle, the situation seems the same as falling into a massive body. But there is a slight difference. During the approaching, other objects placed at different distances in his frame would keep that distances in the first case. But they would be changing in the second one. That means: everything follows geodesics, there is no force acting, but distances between points in what was a frame are now changing. That is what can be called: 'other effects of the gravitational field'. That is no more a Minkowski space-time, and the equivalence principle is valid only as a local approximation.

So, the answer is yes. The fact that the observer is in free falling is not a criteria to calculate its time dilation.

The case of an observer in orbit is still more clear, because there is no orbits in a Minkowski space-time.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is whether an observer in free-fall about a massive object experiences the gravitational time dilation associated with that object.

Nothing "experiences" time dilation. You can measure time dilation by comparing an accurate clock in your reference frame with an accurate clock in another reference frame. But as far as you are concerned time as experienced by you (and as measured by an accurate clock in your reference frame) always passes at the same rate of one second per second.

Time dilation can be observed as a result of a difference in velocity between one reference frame and another or as a result of a difference in acceleration between one reference frame and another. In the first case, because velocity differences are relative (there is no absolute measure of velocity - all inertial reference frames are equivalent), then time dilation due to a difference in velocity alone is symmetric. Each observer will think that time is passing more slowly in the other observer's reference frame.

In the second case, because acceleration is absolute (in the sense that an accelerated observer can tell that their reference frame is not inertial) and *not* relative, time dilation due to a difference in acceleration is *not* symmetric. If one observer is in an inertial reference frame and the other is in an accelerated reference frame and they account for time dilation due to their different velocities then they will agree on the remaining time dilation effect - time passes more slowly in the accelerated reference frame. The greater the acceleration, the more slowly time passes.

And due to the [equivalence principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle), what is true for an accelerated reference frame is also true for an observer in a equivalent gravitational field.

So if we compare clocks on the ISS with clocks on the surface of the Earth there are two time dilation effects. One is due to their relative velocities, which is symmetric. The other is due to the fact that the ISS is an inertial reference frame (it is in free fall) and the surface of the Earth is not, which is an absolute effect.

Comment: Time dilation is never due to acceleration. Gravitational time dilation is related to gravitational potential, not acceleration.

Comment: @EricSmith If there were no time dilation in an accelerated reference frame then an accelerated observer could tell by local observation that they were being accelerated and not in an equivalent gravitation field. But the equivalence principle says that no local observation can tell the difference between an accelerated reference frame and equivalent curved spacetime due to a gravitational field. Therefore time dilation in an accelerated reference frame must be identical to that in an equivalent gravitational field.

Comment: @safesphere An observer can tell that they are either accelerated or in an equivalent gravitational field by local observations - they will observe "pseudoforces" that they either attribute to their acceleration or to gravity. Therefore acceleration is absolute in the sense that an accelerated observer can tell that their reference frame is not an inertial reference frame - although they cannot distinguish between an accelerated reference frame and a gravitational field.

Comment: @safesphere To clarify, I meant to say an observer can tell that they are either accelerated or in an equivalent gravitational field by local observations *but cannot tell which applies* ...

Comment: @safesphere proper acceleration is invariant. Coordinate acceleration is relative.

Comment: @gandalf61 other than the small correction I just posted, the objections are correct. Gravitational time dilation is based on gravitational potential, not gravitational acceleration. That is true both in an accelerating frame and in a gravitational field. The equivalence principle applies, but you are misapplying it. There are examples of fields with no local acceleration, but with a gravitational potential.

Comment: @gandalf61 Even in an accelerated reference frame time dilation is based on potential, not acceleration. Consider an accelerating rocket with clocks at front and rear. Both clocks are accelerating the same, but the front clock ticks faster relative to the rear clock.

Comment: @safesphere you are confusing proper acceleration and coordinate acceleration. A local observer most definitely can tell if they are undergoing proper acceleration. They simply look at an accelerometer they carry locally.

Comment: @safesphere your accelerometer measures proper acceleration, by definition. Your wife is talking about coordinate acceleration. They are different things, which is why one can be g while the other is 0.

Comment: I think my question has been answered.  The free fall observer cannot detect the gravitational field.  Neither can he (or anyone) detect their own time dilation.

Comment: @safesphere coordinate acceleration is the second derivative of position. Proper acceleration is what an accelerometer reads. An accelerometer need not be at rest to produce a reading. Proper acceleration is invariant. Coordinate acceleration is not. They are different things as your own example showed. Accelerometers **never** measure gravity, they measure real forces. Remember in your own example your accelerometer measures g upwards. Gravity is downward, it is the real normal force that points up in that scenario. Your own example contradicts you in multiple ways

Comment: @safesphere excellent! Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

You say the observer in free fall observes nothing about the gravity except time dilation.

But they do. Without gravity they would move in a straight line. But they move in a circle around a heavy body.